# how do i add mp4 files to edit?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a sony handycam which is HD and I've been trying to edit some videos using Blender video editor but its not registering my video files anywhere. I saved them from my camcorder to my computer (on my desktop) but when I click open, they aren't there. I have files in avchd (which are apparently standard on this camcorder) and in mp4 formats. I have done the settings for mp files but its still not there. Please help me so I can edit my movies from my camcorder.
Thank you

Comment: This might be a bug, the files may be corrupted, or any number things. How did you get the files from AVCHD to mp4?

Comment: Did you open the movie file via file --> open?  Or did you open the movie file in the video sequence editor add --> movie? The last option should work and the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **open the AVCHD file as if it were a folder** (it is). In Mac: Right click, then "Show contents". You will see another folder, do the same with it. Then **you'll find the *.MTS files**. Those you can open and work with in Blender.

You can even change the extension "mts" to "mpg", but that's not necessary in Blender.